# Using 1:n table relationships in rule-based symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, relates, rule-based

I would like to use the value of a field/attribute in a parent table as a filter in an expression used to display features in the child table.

Specifically, I have a 1:n relationship in my project:

**Sectors** (parent table with polygon geometry, a key "FID" and a field/attribute "TYPE")

**Trees** (child table with point geometry, and a secondary key "SECTORS_ID")

I would like to use this relationship in the rule-based symbology rendered so that, for example:

*Trees whose parent Sectors have "TYPE" = 'Project'* are displayed as a blue circle

*Trees whose parent Sectors have "TYPE" = 'Parking'* are displayed as a red circle

My question:

How do I build my expression in the rule-based renderer so that I can differentiate between Trees related to a Sector of a specific type?

The condition is not spatial (refFunction plugin is not used), and it should only be based on the value of the parent attribute "TYPE".

I'd rather avoid the following, but: how would I create a virtual field "SECTOR_TYPE" in my child table that would be filled with the value of the "TYPE" field located in the corresponding parent feature?

I am using QGIS 3.10.1

Comment: I assume you're using shapefiles?

Comment: I have both layers in the same geopackage file.